# Merit doesn't add points to user after create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, merit-gem

I've used this instructions for simply add score when a user creates a "solucion" (which is a kind of "answer" to a micropost). I have added the `has_merit` line to user.rb (user model).

I want to display the user points earned for that action at the show view.
show.html.erb (for solucion):

```
<h2><span class="red"><%= current_user.points %></span><br>Points</br></h2>
```

**It displays 0 points...**

point_rules.rb:

```
module Merit
  class PointRules
   include Merit::PointRulesMethods

   def initialize
    score 5, on: 'solucions#create'
   end
  end
end
```

When I create a solucion with the current_user (already saving the user_id index and identifier to solucion), This is what my rails server output shows...

**Direct link to github gist:**

https://gist.github.com/roadev/7b34fd67ab93c979fa48

**Embed:**

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/roadev/7b34fd67ab93c979fa48.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

solucions_micropost.rb

```
  class SolucionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_solucion, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @solucions = Solucion.all
  end
  def show
  end
  def new
    @solucion = current_user.solucions.build
  end
  def edit
  end
  def create
    @solucion = current_user.solucions.build(solucion_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @solucion.save
        format.html { redirect_to @solucion, notice: 'Solucion was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @solucion }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @solucion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @solucion.update(solucion_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @solucion, notice: 'Solucion was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @solucion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @solucion.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to solucions_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_solucion
      @solucion = Solucion.find(params[:id])
    end
    def current_micropost
      @solucion = microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end
    def solucion_params
      params.require(:solucion).permit(:solucion, :image, :micropost_id)
    end
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dreams
  has_many :microposts
  has_many :solucions

  has_merit
end
```

Comment: Without seeing more code (controllers, tests, etc) there's not much help I can provide. One thing that caught my eye: do you mean "solution"?

Comment: Should be "solution" but, it was a problem with the developer (spanish speaker) who generated that model some weeks ago...
Anyway, I'm gonna post the controllers code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with a migration when I installed the merit gem.